# Most efficient way to implement security/ authorization in a coporate environment?

Tags: .net, security, active-directory, authorization, azman

I work in a corporate environment and most of  our applications are developed using Win Forms. We have used azman as a way to manage user roles for the various functions that exist on the applications and tie these back to Active Directory. We have now upgraded our servers to Server 2012, where the .NET applications are now hosted and used by our users via Citrix clients. I would like to find out if there is an alternative to using Azman as developers to manage roles and what the best way to implement security is in such an environment?

Comment: Have you already looked at Windows Identity Foundation?

Comment: Yes I have read up a little on WIF. I think I would still need a tool like Azman to manage roles.